# Null Reference Exception Unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem in Unity 2d

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   RightOne.OnMouseDown () (at Assets/Scripts/RightOne.cs:13)
>   UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)

Here's the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RightOne : MonoBehaviour {

    private GameObject mainCube;

    void Start () {
        mainCube = GameObject.Find ("Main Cube");
    }

    void OnMouseDown () {
        if (GetComponent <Renderer> ().material.color == mainCube.GetComponent <Renderer> ().material.color)
            mainCube.GetComponent <GameCntrl> ().next = true;
        else
            mainCube.GetComponent <GameCntrl> ().lose = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that something in your code in that function is `null` for example, `GameObject.Find(..)` returns null if the object cannot be found. `GetComponent<T>()` can also return null.

You need to make sure the gamecube is found, and the current gameobject and the main cube actually have a renderer component attached. The same is true for the `GameCntrl` component.

Comment: Thank you very much! You really help me!! There are a problem with name of a "Main Cube"!!))

Comment: @MaksNeon great you found the problem, go ahead and mark this as answered if this question is done